# File reader program isn't printing full alphabet of words

Tags: java, project, filereader

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReadFile {
    public static TreeMap<String, Integer> generateFrequencyList()
            throws IOException {
        TreeMap<String, Integer> wordsFrequencyMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        String file = "file1.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            for (String token : tokens) {
                token = removePunctuation(token);
                if (!wordsFrequencyMap.containsKey(token.toLowerCase())) {
                    wordsFrequencyMap.put(token.toLowerCase(), 1);
                } else {
                    int count = wordsFrequencyMap.get(token.toLowerCase());
                    wordsFrequencyMap.put(token.toLowerCase(), count + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return wordsFrequencyMap;
    }

    private static String removePunctuation(String token) {
        token = token.replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("\\.", "").replaceAll(";", "").replaceAll("!", "");
        return token;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TreeMap<String, Integer> freqMap = generateFrequencyList();
            for (final Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : freqMap.entrySet()) {
                final String key = entry.getKey();
                final Integer value = entry.getValue();
                float total = 0;
                for (final Integer wordCount : freqMap.values()) {
                    total += wordCount;
                }
                final float percentage = (value / total) * 100;
                System.out.println(key + " = " + value + " => " + percentage);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I need this program to read the .txt file and return a word list, frequency and percentage. The .txt file I am using has more words than this prints out. It seems to be only printing out the words from T - Z. I am not sure how to fix it to give me all of the words. Anyone have some ideas why it does not give me the full word list?

Comment: Can you provide some examples from the file you input.

Comment: See the comment I left in my answer to your other question. Also, you don't need to re-calculate the `total` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me..perhaps your test file and and example might help..
just a tip..while at it might wanna put loop for calculating "total" outside the for loop. :)

> i/p  I need this program to read the .txt file and return a word list,
>   frequency and percentage. The .txt file I am using has more words than
>   this prints out. It seems to be only printing out the words from T -
>   Z. I am not sure how to fix it to give me all of the words. Anyone
>   have some ideas why it does not give me the full word list?

o/p "
- = 1

> => 1.388889 a = 1 => 1.388889 all = 1 => 1.388889 am = 2 => 2.777778 and = 2 => 2.777778 anyone = 1 => 1.388889 be = 1 => 1.388889 does = 1
>   => 1.388889 file = 2 => 2.777778 fix = 1 => 1.388889 frequency = 1 => 1.388889 from = 1 => 1.388889 full = 1 => 1.388889 give = 2 => 2.777778 has = 1 => 1.388889 have = 1 => 1.388889 how = 1 => 1.388889 i = 3 => 4.166667 ideas = 1 => 1.388889 it = 3 => 4.166667 list = 1 =>
>   1.388889 list? = 1 => 1.388889 me = 2 => 2.777778 more = 1 => 1.388889 need = 1 => 1.388889 not = 2 => 2.777778 of = 1 => 1.388889 only = 1
>   => 1.388889 out = 2 => 2.777778 percentage = 1 => 1.388889 printing = 1 => 1.388889 prints = 1 => 1.388889 program = 1 => 1.388889 read = 1
>   => 1.388889 return = 1 => 1.388889 seems = 1 => 1.388889 some = 1 => 1.388889 sure = 1 => 1.388889 t = 1 => 1.388889 than = 1 => 1.388889 the = 5 => 6.9444447 this = 2 => 2.777778 to = 4 => 5.555556 txt = 2
>   => 2.777778 using = 1 => 1.388889 why = 1 => 1.388889 word = 2 => 2.777778 words = 3 => 4.166667 z = 1 => 1.388889"

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and looks fine here also.  Here is my output:

```
a = 5 => 3.164557
accept = 1 => 0.6329114
acceptance = 1 => 0.6329114
accepts = 1 => 0.6329114
and = 1 => 0.6329114
any = 3 => 1.8987341
applicable = 1 => 0.6329114
are = 2 => 1.2658228
at = 2 => 1.2658228
available = 1 => 0.6329114
be = 4 => 2.5316455
been = 1 => 0.6329114
being = 1 => 0.6329114
billed = 1 => 0.6329114
buy = 1 => 0.6329114
by = 2 => 1.2658228
can = 1 => 0.6329114
card = 1 => 0.6329114
charge = 1 => 0.6329114
charges = 1 => 0.6329114
confirmation = 1 => 0.6329114
constitute = 1 => 0.6329114
credit = 1 => 0.6329114
customer = 2 => 1.2658228
deposit = 1 => 0.6329114
direct = 1 => 0.6329114
do = 1 => 0.6329114
does = 1 => 0.6329114
email = 3 => 1.8987341
for = 3 => 1.8987341
from = 2 => 1.2658228
hardware = 1 => 0.6329114
has = 1 => 0.6329114
if = 2 => 1.2658228
is = 1 => 0.6329114
lenovo = 3 => 1.8987341
lenovo's = 1 => 0.6329114
limit = 1 => 0.6329114
locations = 1 => 0.6329114
made = 1 => 0.6329114
making = 1 => 0.6329114
may = 1 => 0.6329114
multiple = 1 => 0.6329114
no = 1 => 0.6329114
not = 3 => 1.8987341
notify = 1 => 0.6329114
number = 1 => 0.6329114
of = 2 => 1.2658228
once = 1 => 0.6329114
one = 1 => 0.6329114
only = 1 => 0.6329114
or = 5 => 3.164557
order = 5 => 3.164557
orders = 1 => 0.6329114
particular = 1 => 0.6329114
payment = 1 => 0.6329114
phone = 1 => 0.6329114
processed = 2 => 1.2658228
product = 4 => 2.5316455
providing = 1 => 0.6329114
purchase = 1 => 0.6329114
reason = 1 => 0.6329114
receive = 1 => 0.6329114
refunded = 1 => 0.6329114
refuse = 1 => 0.6329114
reserves = 1 => 0.6329114
right = 1 => 0.6329114
sell = 1 => 0.6329114
service = 1 => 0.6329114
shipped = 2 => 1.2658228
shipping = 4 => 2.5316455
single = 1 => 0.6329114
software = 1 => 0.6329114
some = 1 => 0.6329114
thank = 1 => 0.6329114
that = 1 => 0.6329114
the = 5 => 3.164557
this = 2 => 1.2658228
time = 2 => 1.2658228
to = 6 => 3.7974682
units = 1 => 0.6329114
updates = 1 => 0.6329114
we = 2 => 1.2658228
will = 5 => 3.164557
you = 5 => 3.164557
your = 8 => 5.063291
```

Just FYI I did add br.close() since my editor was complaining about the BufferReader not being closed.  However this does not affect the ouput.

```
     }
    }
    br.close();
    return wordsFrequencyMap;
```

Comment: I'm so confused, mine is not printing all the words. Could it be my .txt file?